# Scatter plot and contour plot with same colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

Is it possible to force `plt.scatter` into the same color levels as `plt.contourf` and `plt.contour`? For example, I have code that makes a plot like this:

[image]

to make the first subplot, I use

```
cs=m[0].scatter(xs,ys,c=obsData,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
m.colorbar(cs)
```

To make the second subplot, I use

```
cs2=m[1].contourf(x,y,areaData,cmap=cs.cmap)
```

And for each subsequent subplot, I use

```
m[ind].contourf(x,y,areaData,cmap=cs.cmap,levels=cs2.levels
```

where areaData is recalculated within a loop.

My question is, how can I force the first subplot to have the same colors as the other subplots? I am looking for an equivalent to the `levels=cs2.levels` keyword argument.

Comment: The scatter plot is coloured by `obsData`, but the contour plots are coloured according to `areaData`. The sacatter plot has values above 8, the contours values below 7. Are you sure these data correspond to the same data set? Otherwise it doesn't make any sense to force the same colormap for both. Am I missing something?

Comment: They aren't from the same dataset, in fact, none of the subplots are from the same dataset. Despite that difference, obsData is observed  error data from the simulation, while areaData is data containing uncertainty from the simulation do to varying factors. I want to compare the error to the uncertainty, but to do so properly, requires uniform coloring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted in a comment, your scatter and contour data are not directly related, but you want to display them on the same colormap.

I suggest setting a common colour span that contains both sets of data. Since `obsData` refers to the scatter points and `areaData` to the contours, I'd set

```
vmin,vmax = (fun(np.concatenate([obsData,areaData])) for fun in (np.min,np.max))
```

to determine the span of the collected data set (obviously, to be generalized for multiple input data sets). These can be passed to `scatter` and `contourf` to set the limits of the colour mapping:

```
cs = m[0].scatter(xs,ys,c=obsData,cmap=plt.cm.viridis,vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax)
cs2 = m[1].contourf(x,y,areaData,cmap=cs.cmap,vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax)
```

Some manual increase of the span might be in order to obtain a pretty result.

Note that I changed the colormap to `viridis`. If you really want to fairly represent your data, [this should be your first step](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAoljeRJ3lU).